# Anyone know how to remove unwanted animation from navigation bar? Screenshots

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller which proceeds via a button to a table view controller.

In the view controller, the navigation bar is totally translucent (As you can see in the screen shot below). On the table view controller, the navigation bar is set to white.

My problem is, when I press 'back' in the table view and return to the view controller, the white navigation bar is carried over for a moment (see top image) before disappearing in an ugly animation.

Extra Navigation bar space: 
[image: Unwanted navigation bar carry over]

How I want it to always look:
[image: How it should look]

I have tried pretty much everything I can think of, all  my code relating to the navigation bars translucency is in viewDidAppear, so why is this happening!?

Someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong! This is making me crazy!

Comment: sorry , i'm not getting that exactly… are u saying that on pressing "back" u see two navigation bars one below other ?

Comment: Hi NickAtStack, thanks for your comment! I think what was actually happening was the non-transparent navigation bar from the table view controller was traveling back to the view controller, and pushing the image down (from where it usually sits under the translucent bar). Then the navigation bar was becoming translucent and it was all being shunted up automatically! 
Of course, I was just being stupid and not fixing the issue in viewWillDissapear as Nikos suggested. I think its time for more coffee!

Comment: :D yes, nikos said it right,. You can make the best possible solution with using those view functions of both controllers

Comment: @nickAtStack perhaps you will know the answer to this follow on issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634448/how-to-remove-unwanted-black-area-during-navigation-bar-animation-screen-shots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tableviewcontroller set:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 // put the code for the uinavigation bar styling here.
}
```

Comment: exactly right, I have no idea why I didn't think of this. Thank you very much for your help. One last thing, as I'm removing the navigation bar as the view disappears, it shows up as a black square during the animation to the previous page. Do you know any way to stop this happening? Or just remove the animation completely?

Comment: I have asked a new question about this, please head over and check it out! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634448/how-to-remove-unwanted-black-area-during-navigation-bar-animation-screen-shots

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this have a custom back button below is the code

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(2, 1, 29, 29);
[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO
item.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

where item is instance of UINavigationItem
and in selector of back button

-(void)backButtonClicked:(id)sender {

```
[self.navigationBar popNavigationItemAnimated:NO];
```

}

by doing this the navigation bar will pop the item but without animation.