# How to remove unwanted black area during navigation bar animation. Screen shots

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar, transparency

I have a view controller, in which the navigation bar is transparent. My next view is a table view, in which the navigation bar is white.

To stop an unwanted animation carrying over, I am setting the navigation bar to transparent in the 'viewDidDissapear' of the table view. Unfortunately this leaves me with the image below when I navigate back (its even worse when you navigate forward). Does anyone know how to get rid of the black area?

[image: This shows the unwanted black area]

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated     {


[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;


[super viewWillDisappear:NO];

}
```

This is the code I'm using in the table view controller.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, UNWANTED ANIMATIONS ,. i would suggest you to set     (animated:NO)   in both (presentViewController  & dismissViewController) of your tableViewController……… and set your navigation bars in viewWillAppear of both controllers.. best and easy i think..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you give me a little code on the presenting and dismissing view controllers? Its not something I've done before (always relied on navigation controllers to do it for me). Where in the tableViewController should I be calling them?

Comment: No, don't be confused… if you're using navigation controller, they mean pushViewController and popViewController      …just set     animated:NO    to them

Comment: notify me with the changes or mark as answer if it did the job for you :)

Comment: Hi Nick, I think I'm having a slow day - Im really confused here. I have tried various work-arounds and nothing seems to be working. I can  I'm really sorry for being so stupid, but can you elaborate for me a little more?

Comment: Add self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO; in viewWillAppear